# Xamarin Android C# Image Correlation similar to aforge

Tags: c#, android, mono, xamarin, xamarin.android

I'm currently developing an app for Windows and Android using Xamarin (mono) C# for the android side that has to compare 2 images and return the correlation as a percentage.

Currently for the windows app i'm using aForge.net, specifically the ExhaustiveTemplateMatching function which works really well but is dependent on the System.Drawing.Bitmap which is not available for android.

I'm looking for a solution for the android side which will perform similarly (doesn't have to be 100% the same). I did look into aforge.net PCL but this seems to be incomplete on the android side as far as I could tell when trying to set it up with Shim.Drawing. I also looked into emguCV but the licensing cost makes it a non option.

Are there any other solutions that I can use to easily determine matches between 2 images on android that can easily be integrated using Xamarin C#?

Comment: I notice you have tried to use the [portable version of AForge.NET](https://github.com/cureos/aforge), of which I am the maintainer. In the Github repository, there is no Android version of *Shim.Drawing*, but I have developed one internally. If you are further interested in obtaining an Android *Shim.Drawing* assembly that will enable you to develop both with AForge.NET and Accord.NET for Android, please contact me at *licences at cureos dot com*.

Comment: Thanks that's definitely a good fit. Still looking for options though that are free to use in closed source apps.